# How to scan matrix by row after using csvRead in Scilab?

Tags: data-science, scilab

`data=csvRead("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Iris.csv",",","%f");`

Is the code I used in Scilab to read the file which contains this:

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor

and so on...

> now what I want to do is to manipulate the data by row and apply it to a clustering algorithm.
>   For example I want to use each of the values in row one to calculate their euclidian distance between the centroids.
>
> How would I know the index of each value and how do use it in computations?
>
> I want to manipulate the data just like this code in Java.

```
for(i=0; i < popnSize; i++){  
        for(j=0; j < dim; j++){
            System.out.println("["+i+"]" + arrpop[i][j]+"\t"); 
        }
```

> How would you translate that in Scilab after reading the matrix using csvRead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
--> data=csvRead("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Iris.csv",",","%f");
```

computing the distance to the centroid can be done by centering the data matrix in the row direction then computing the norm of each row:

```
--> dist = sqrt(sum(center(data(:,1:4),1).^2,2))
 dist  = 

   0.6407461
   0.7168604
   0.8566732
   0.8065702
   0.7074995
   3.4274221
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as follow:

```
for i=1:popnSize
    for j=1:dim
        printf("[%d]%g\t",i, arrpop(i,j))
    end
end
```